# iOS. Интеграция и архитектура приложения (Solution design)

Tags: ios7, клиент-сервер, integration-services

Каким образом происходит взаимодействие приложения и серверной части. По направлению приложение-> server - очевидно использование RESTAPI интеграции, но каким образом происходить взаимодействие между сервером и приложением. Как серверная часть передает данные на приложение? Насколько мне известно андроид приложения для этих целей используют RESTAPI на applicatio.google.com а как это построено для iOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Интегация с приложением iOS для push уведомлений происходит с помощью сервиса  Apple Push Notification Service (APNS). 
Детальная информация здесь: http://www.catapush.com/docs-ios